# Use of ODBC and Relational connections in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I noticed that in the mapping level we are creating the ODBC connection and in the Workflow level we are creating the Relational connection. What are those 2 connections needed for?

Comment: Make question clearer

Answer (score 0):

Question is crystal clear.

When you create the mapping you are describing what you want the data to do and shouldn't be restricted by whether the data model exists yet or not.

In order to do this you need to know the structure of your source and target but you don't need to actually connect to them. Having a dummy csv to get you going in mapping designer and while the dba builds the tables in the database is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer you may connect to existing structure to create Source or Target transformations. But you just create the structure, the definition - it's not connected to the mapping anymore.

In the workflow designer you choose a connection that should process data strutured in a way described by the Source or Target definition. It's the connection that will be used to access the data.